# VisualStudio SDK LanguageService samples

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for examples of LanguageService usage. The samples for the latest VSSDK 2013 do have a language implementation for "Ook" but for whatever reason it doesn't use LanguageService and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166215.aspx says that's what I need to do to implement a custom language in VS.

I'm having issues with custom coloring of tokens but because the docs are unorganized and little to no examples are provided I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this as an answer but I won't accept it because it isn't exactly what I was looking for. It is however, the best that I could find:

https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YAMLLanguage/YAMLLanguageService.cs